# present ViewController using lldb

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, viewcontroller, lldb

Is there a way to present a VewController directly form lldb debugger. 
I am talking about using something like:

```
(lldb) expression SomeViewController.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` doesn't present anything.

Comment: @rmaddy ups, ok, then how ?

Comment: Forget the debugger for a moment. Do you know how to present a view controller in your app?

Comment: @rmaddy self.present(VC, animated: true)

Comment: Then try that in the debugger. Remember, you need to try code that would actually compile and work in your app.

Comment: @rmaddy the thing is that it's executing, but my screen is not updating

Comment: No.  That's not something you can do from the debugger.  Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth oh yes you can https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/#pushing-a-view-controller

Comment: Have you tried that when debugging a Swift app?  It kind of works if you change it to Swift code but I can't get my view controller to present until I continue.  Still I have learnt something new.

Comment: It might work for pushing onto a UINavigationController but I can't get it working for presenting a UIViewController otherwise.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth hey, that's it, that's why my screen was not updating, I just had to press or type continue

Comment: Cool so it's working now.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth yup yup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `expression` command available in the debugger, which allows you to execute code - much like the Javascript console in a web browser.

In this case, you want to:

1. pause execution of the app (Ctrl+Cmd+Y).
2. select "main" on the call stack in the Debug navigator (Cmd+7)
3. write the following in the debugger:

`e UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true)`, where `viewController` is the VC instance you want to present.

4. the VC will show up as soon as you resume execution (another Ctrl+Cmd+Y).

Comment: what happens if the VC you want to show is not in the WindowHierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/facebook/chisel - it adds some useful commands to the debugger, including `fvc` and `pvc`, which allow you to inspect view controllers.

Comment: Oh, wait! You meant actually presenting a VC in the app, not just printing it in the debugger my bad - I'm going to leave this answer in case its useful to someone in the future, and add a separate one for the actual answer to your question.